# ASP Web service insists on being called via post

Tags: asp.net, web-services

It seems that the asp web service insists on being called via a POST request.

How can I make it accept my GET request?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to modify your web.config to include something like this:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpSoap"/> 
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2c0ew36%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: thanks! that did the trick with the addition of the location tag: <location path="WebService.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <webServices>
        <protocols>
         <add name="HttpPost"/>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
  </location>